# use img instead of text label in d3.js line chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/2hfx3/57/)

I couldn't get `ordinal scales` to work with zooming and panning to achieve horizontally scroll-able effect so I have settled for `scale.linear()` to use numeric values for axis ticks. I was wondering if it is possible to superimpose the text label in `g.tick` with an image element. I have come up with this code after `.call(xAxis)`

```
svg.append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll(".tick text").each(function(k,i){
      console.log(data[k]["img"]);      
      var r = document.createElement('image')
          r.setAttribute('x',0)
          r.setAttribute('y',9)
          r.setAttribute('xlink:href',data[k]["img"])
          r.setAttribute('width',50)
          r.setAttribute('height',50)
          this.parentNode.insertBefore(r,this);
    })
```

I saw that the elements are prepended in `g.tick` but the images are nowhere to be seen. Is it because of the `x` and `y` values? Also, how can I bind the image links from the JSON data to the `image` element? I have tried `data[k]["img"]` but it gave me `Cannot read property 'img' of undefined`.

```
var img = "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/904fd39461599f72d580fadf3a73115b?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1";

var data = [{"item":1,"diameter":"15.00","img":img},{"item":2,"diameter":"10.00","img":img},
{"item":3,"diameter":"25.00","img":img},{"item":4,"diameter":"7.00","img":img},
{"item":5,"diameter":"35.00","img":img},{"item":6,"diameter":"15.00","img":img},
{"item":7,"diameter":"12.00","img":img},{"item":8,"diameter":"10.00","img":img},
{"item":9,"diameter":"17.00","img":img},{"item":10,"diameter":"13.00","img":img},
{"item":11,"diameter":"5.00","img":img},{"item":12,"diameter":"10.00","img":img},
];
function line_chart(field,el){ 
  margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 45
  },
  tickno = 10,

  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 450 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
  x = d3.scale.linear().domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
      return d.item;
  })).range([0, width]),

  ymax = d3.max(data,function(d){
    return (parseInt(d[field])+1);
  }),

  ymin = d3.min(data,function(d){
    return d[field];
  }),

  xmax = d3.max(data,function(d){
    return d.name;
  }),

  y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([ymin,ymax])
    .range([height, 0]);

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function (d) {
      return x(d.item);
    })
    .y(function (d) {
      return y(d[field]);
    });

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .x(x)
    .scaleExtent([1, 1])
    .y(y)
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

svg = d3.select(el)
    .append("svg:svg")
    .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("svg:g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .call(zoom);

svg.append("svg:rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("class", "plot");

var make_x_axis = function () {
    return d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom")
        .ticks(tickno);
 };

var make_y_axis = function () {
    return d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left")
        .ticks(tickno);
};

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(tickno);


svg.append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll(".tick text").each(function(data){      
      var r = document.createElement('image')
          r.setAttribute('x',0)
          r.setAttribute('y',9)
        r.setAttribute('xlink:href','https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/904fd39461599f72d580fadf3a73115b?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1')
          r.setAttribute('width',50)
          r.setAttribute('height',50)
          this.parentNode.insertBefore(r,this);
    })

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(tickno);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x grid")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(make_x_axis()
    .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
    .tickFormat(""));

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y grid")
    .call(make_y_axis()
    .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
    .tickFormat(""));

var clip = svg.append("svg:clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("svg:rect")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var chartBody = svg.append("g")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");

chartBody.append("svg:path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line);

svg.append('g').attr('class','dots').selectAll(".dot").data(data).enter().append("circle").attr("r",3.5)
.attr("cx",function(d){return x(d.item);})
.attr("cy",function(d){return y(d[field]);})

function zoomed() {
    console.log(d3.event.translate);
    console.log(d3.event.scale);
    svg.select(".dots")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" +  d3.event.scale + ")");

    svg.selectAll(".dots circle").attr("r", function(){
       return (3.5  * d3.event.scale);
    });

    svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
    svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
    svg.select(".x.grid")
        .call(make_x_axis()
        .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
        .tickFormat(""));
    svg.select(".y.grid")
        .call(make_y_axis()
        .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
        .tickFormat(""));
    svg.select(".line")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", line);
    svg.selectAll(".dots circle").attr("r", function(){
     return (3.5  * d3.event.scale);
    });
  }
}
line_chart('diameter','#area')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your image doesn't display because your width is too small.

Also, it's a bit cleaner if you append the images the `d3` way:

```
.selectAll(".tick").each(function(d,i){        
    d3.select(this)
      .append('image')
      .attr('xlink:href', data[i].img)
      .attr('x',0)
      .attr('width',128)
      .attr('height',128);
 })
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2hfx3/61/).